# Pubsubhubbub plugin for Joomla

Tags: joomla, websub

Does anyone know if a Pubsubhubbub plugin for Joomla exists? For example, I found the following plugins for Wordpress and Drupal:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pubsubhubbub/
- http://drupal.org/project/push_hub

I did search before asking :) , but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of any... even though I contribute heavily to the PubSubHubbub community. On the other end, it should really be quite easy to create one.
There are a couple 'Pinging' modules like [Easy Ping](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/site-verification/8488) or [Blog Ping](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog/7702) (I didn't test any though), which should be easy to fork into doing PubSubHubbub pings to hubs.